# Cocos2d android not pausing the game

Tags: cocos2d-android

i want to pause my game i used the following code but its not pausing when we return from any interrupt its shows the main menu screen.its starting from 1st again.

It is expected that if user gives any sort of interrupt during action phase of the game then after returning back from the interrupt game should pause at the exact location where interrupt occurred displaying pause screen with required options.

CCDirector.sharedDirector().pause();

Answer (score 0):

I got this issue solved. The problem is with the screen orientation change. The game is in landscape mode, when the device sleeps the screen orientation automatically changes to portrait mode. This results in restarting the activity. 
Adding android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation" to the activity in the manifest solves the issue.